# Is it possible to autowire method arguments at runtime in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autowired

Is it possible to inject new instances of prototype scoped beans to Controller's method arguments at runtime using annotations in Spring? So whenever the method is called, Spring would inject the qualifying bean as its argument, familiarly as it injects @ModelAttribute. As far as I know, @Autowired fields are injected only once when context is created. Obtaining the bean from context's factory method isn't an option, as that would expose framework to its component, thus violating the hollywood principle.

I have almost completed reading Spring in Action book and have been reading Spring Reference a lot, but haven't found any info regarding this question.

Comment: Why are you wanting to inject prototypes there? This seems like a code smell. (If it really is reasonable, you could always inject a factory instead of the produced bean.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

Define a prototype bean and inject that wrapped in an `ObjectFactory`

```
@Autowired
private ObjectFactory<PrototypeBean> factory;
```

You can then retrieve it in your handler method. For example

```
@RequestMapping("/path")
public String handlerMethod() {
    PrototypeBean instance = factory.getObject();
    instance.someMethod();
    return "view";
}
```

Every time you call `factory.getObject()`, you'll get a new instance.

As for doing this directly, no, Spring MVC does not have a built-in feature for having beans injected while invoking handler methods, with `@Autowired` or otherwise.

However, the [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/invocation/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) API allows you to define an implementation for any type of parameter you want. You can define a new annotation and use it to annotate the appropriate handler method parameter(s). The implementation would look for the annotation and resolve an instance from an injected `ApplicationContext`. You could do this by name, by type, however you want.

Comment: I combined `ObjectFactory` with `@ModelAttribute` and it worked as excepted, thanks. I also found alternative JSR-standard interface called `Provider`. Even found out about `@Lookup` but it felt little unintuitive

Comment: I made further experimenting with `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, and finally managed to get it work right after declaring it as a `component` so I can bind it with `context`, and then adding the autowired instance manually to a list of resolvers in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. Is it legacy class, or why can't I just define it as a bean and let Spring detect it and integrate it to it's infrastructure, like ViewResolvers etc. ?